# Created new Gmail account while logged in with non-Gmail email

Tags: gmail, google-account

I created a new Gmail account for my daughter while logged on as myself (account was created using non-Gmail address). While I was doing it, it asked if I want to be able to manage this email using existing account. I clicked yes.

And now I have an account, where main email is my daughter's and I can't change it because it's Gmail and as such it is non-removable.

I can pass my account to her completely, but I can't create new account using my email, because it already exists. I can remove it, but I still won't be able to, because it seems that removed account is not really removed.

I'm pretty sure nothing said I'm setting up new email for my account - I was creating new Gmail address.

Is there a way out of this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary email address of your Google account was "converted" to an alternative email address when you added a Gmail address for your daughter.

From [Remove addresses from your account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/76143?hl=en)

> Here's how to remove an alternate email address from your Google
>   Account:
>
> 1. Sign in to your account at myaccount.google.com.
> 2. Select **Email** in the Personal info box.
> 3. Select **Edit** next to Other emails.
> 4. Under "Change your associated email addresses," select the "X" to **Remove**.
>
> [See what usernames](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/70206)
>   you can remove from your Google Account.

Comment: But I want to keep that email for password retrieval "in case of". Can I do what you suggest and have my way too? Or it will still block me from creating new account for me?

Comment: Yes you can do what I suggest and use your email address as a recovery email address. For the instructions to set a recovery email address for your Google Account see [Set up a recovery phone number or email address - Google Accounts Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/183723?hl=en)